# Kaminari Link modification in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, kaminari

Using kaminari , i currently generate link something like below

```
http://localhost:3000/San-Jose_CA?page=52&pgsz=20
```

But how can i restructure it like below

```
http://localhost:3000/San-Jose_CA/pg-52?pgsz=20
```

Comment: While not directly answer your question, Kaminari document [Creating friendly URLs and caching](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#creating-friendly-urls-and-caching) might help you.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't. It just shows only one way. I am looking for another way

Answer (score -1):

You can add following in your routes.rb

```
      concern :paginatable do

        get '(page/:page)', :action => :index, :on => :collection, :as => ''

      end


  resources :resource_name, :concerns => :paginatable
```

see https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#creating-friendly-urls-and-caching